# Omitting certain lines of a .csv file with less no. of columns and reading the rest

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, algorithmic-trading, read.csv

I have high frequency data in a **`.csv`** file that consists of order quotes and trade quotes. Following is an example of the first 13 lines of a 600,000 line dataset: (sorry for the format, copy/paste wouldn't fit all the columns on one line hence I have spaced them out)

```
1442527200000750850 11539422 15110 1 1 15120 4 3 15105 1 1 15125 17 2 15100 4 3 15130 8 2 15095 7 6 15135 3 1 15090 33 3 15140 3 1 15085 1 1 15145 4 4 15080 2 1 15150 2 2 15075 2 2 15160 2 2 15070 1 1 15165 3 2 0 0 0 15170 6 1

1442527200000750850 11539422 15110 1 1 15120 4 3 15105 1 1 15125 17 2 15100 4 3 15130 8 2 15095 7 6 15135 3 1 15090 33 3 15140 3 1 15085 1 1 15145 4 4 15080 2 1 15150 2 2 15075 2 2 15160 2 2 15070 1 1 15165 3 2 15060 3 3 15170 6 1

1442527200000750850 11539422 15110 1 1 15120 2 2 15105 1 1 15125 17 2 15100 4 3 15130 8 2 15095 7 6 15135 3 1 15090 33 3 15140 3 1 15085 1 1 15145 4 4 15080 2 1 15150 2 2 15075 2 2 15160 2 2 15070 1 1 15165 3 2 15060 3 3 15170 6 1

1442527200024857519 11539479 15115 1 1 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 3 1 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 1 1 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 2 2 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 6 1

1442527200024960184 11539480 15115 2 2 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 3 1 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 1 1 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 2 2 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 6 1

1442527200025091242 11539482 15115 2 2 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 3 1 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 1 1 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 2 2 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 7 2

1442527200060240623 11539555 15115 2 2 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 3 1 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 1 1 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 3 3 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 7 2

1442527200065644806 11539556 15115 2 2 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 4 2 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 1 1 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 3 3 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 7 2

1442527200088944431 11539565 15115 2 2 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 4 2 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 2 2 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 3 3 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 7 2

1442527200088944431 11539565 15115 2 2 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 4 2 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 2 2 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 2 2 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 7 2

1442527200323230870 11539621 15115 3 3 15120 2 2 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 4 2 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 2 2 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 2 2 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 7 2

1442527200323600606 11539622 15115 3 3 15120 1 1 15110 1 1 15125 17 2 15105 1 1 15130 8 2 15100 4 3 15135 4 2 15095 7 6 15140 3 1 15090 33 3 15145 4 4 15085 2 2 15150 2 2 15080 2 1 15160 2 2 15075 2 2 15165 3 2 15070 1 1 15170 7 2

1442527200324698612 11539623 15120 1 1
```

As you can see, the last row in this example has only 5 columns while the others have many more. The row with only 5 columns is the trade execution line and rest are order quotes. Basically, I want to read the `csv` file while omitting these trade rows with only 5 columns and read the rest of the file so I can start my analysis on the `Bid`/`Ask` quotes.

I tried using the **`read.csv()`** function, but I can't seem to figure how to code it to skip the trade lines ( 5 column lines ) and only read the order quotes, it reads everything and gives me **`NaN`** for the empty columns in the trade line. I also tried opening a connection and then using the scan function but again faced the same problem. Is there a way I can put in an **`if`** statement somewhere in there and omit the lines or any other way?

In case its needed, the format of the data is following:

```
ORDER_BOOK: ( timestamp_in_ns ) ( feed-sequence-number ) x bid_price_in_USD, bid_qty, number_of_bid_orders, ask_price_in_USD, ask_qty, number_of_ask_orders, .....
```

OR

```
TRADE:      ( timestamp_in_ns ) ( feed-sequence-number ) trade_price_in_USD, trade_qty, trade_side ( 1 for Buy and 2 for Sell, might be 0 if CME doesn't give us this information for some trade )
```

There are no headers in the dataset and objects are separated by **`""`**

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Well, read everything and subset to omit the lines with `NA`s afterwards.

Comment: @Roland. What do you mean? Can you explain?

Comment: Please read [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf). Subsetting should be one of the first techniques to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `complete.cases` to detect the complete rows:

```
X <- read.csv(filename,sep=" ")
X <- X[-which(!complete.cases(X)),]
```